# Output Code Once if Conditional is True for One or More Entries in a Group

Tags: categories, conditionals, gwcode-categories, mx-calculator

I'm displaying a list of categories, and I want to add a little "new" icon next to the category name if one or more entries in that category have been created in the last day. But I can't figure out how to display code just once if multiple entries return true. I got this far using [GWCode Categories](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories) and [MX Calculator](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-calculator):

```
{exp:gwcode_categories
    cat_id='4'
    depth='2'
    show_empty='no'
    style='linear'
    variable_prefix='gw:'
    parse='inward'
}
    <li>
        <a href="{path='topics/{gw:cat_url_title}'}">
            {gw:cat_name}
            <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon=""></span>
            {!-- If an entry in this category has been added in the last day, add the "new" icon --}
            {exp:channel:entries
                channel='{sp_channels}'
                dynamic='no'
                category='{gw:cat_id}'
                disable='categories|pagination|member_data|custom_fields'
            }
                {exp:mx_calc expression="{current_time} - 86400"}
                    {if {entry_date} > {calc_result}}
                         <b class="new">New</b>
                    {/if}
                {/exp:mx_calc}
            {/exp:channel:entries}
        </a>
    </li>
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

But that outputs the "new" tag once for *every entry* that passes the conditional.

How do I get the code to output *just once* if any entries return true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just add a limit="1" parameter to the channel entries tag it will pull the most recent entry anyway - if you think about it, you only really need to see if that single entry was added in the last day, not the whole lot.

Comment: Ah, of course! That didn't even occur to me, thanks!